# How to know when the weather is rain or snow or sun?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

first i'm sorry because my Eng too bad. I have a question, how i know is it rain or snow ? i try check by temp but its not right . I take data form openweathermap API . 
here is my codepen:
http://codepen.io/khanh1993/full/EybPXG/
and condition to check:

```
if(fTemp>80){
  $("#icon").html('<i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-fw fa-5x fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
  $('body').css("background","url('http://www.walldevil.com/wallpapers/a79/nature-backgrounds-screen-desktop-savers-high-sunshine-wallpapers-images-resolution.jpg')")
}
else if(fTemp>58){
  $("#icon").html('<i class="fa fa-tint fa-fw fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
  $('body').css("background","url('http://wallpapercave.com/wp/doNuhh5.jpg')");
}
else if(fTemp>40){
  $('#icon').html('<i class="fa fa-cloud fa-5x fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
  $('body').css("background","url('http://eskipaper.com/images/cloud-background-6.jpg')");
}
```

Comment: Your codepen url seems wrong

Comment: You're checking against temperature only.  Weather is far more complex than that.  It's not smart to embed logic like this in pages and markup.

Comment: @grateful, the pen isn't wrong, but the content makes you feel that way :D. Weird pen IMO

Comment: @duykhanh where you want to show weather for? if you access a site like http://www.accuweather.com/en/fr/lyon/171210/daily-weather-forecast/171210 you can probably access the icons, but i would examine the source if i were you

Comment: srr im add wrong link :D 
@RachelGallen i want to build current local weather app :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the API doc that i found in openweather API

```
{"coord":{"lon":139,"lat":35},
"sys":{"country":"JP","sunrise":1369769524,"sunset":1369821049},
"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],
"main":{"temp":289.5,"humidity":89,"pressure":1013,"temp_min":287.04,"temp_max":292.04},
"wind":{"speed":7.31,"deg":187.002},
"rain":{"3h":0},
"clouds":{"all":92},
"dt":1369824698,
"id":1851632,
"name":"Shuzenji",
"cod":200}
```

you can get the weather from `response.weather[0].main`

here is how i get that

```
$.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=356c0e149219f8d18d30e05f4e1a130f', function(response){
    console.log(response.weather[0].main)
});
```

the output will be "Rain" right now

Comment: oh i see that , i wrong T.T i just see description :D
how many type of main ? like Rain ,sunshine